# Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, xlsx

I am debugging this code from Github. Here is the link : https://github.com/kaupage/UnicodeToDevnagari/blob/master/UnicodeToDevnagariInscript.bas

I have also created sub functions in the code. But after Array of rKreem_Uni i am getting Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure call or Argument. I have mentioned some arrays after the rKreem_Uni Array. For full code please see the above link.

PFA.

[image: Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure call or Argument]

```
Sub UnicodeToDevnagariInscript()
    'converts Unicode Characters to Devnagari Inscript
    'Use in conjuction with Shree - Unicode version 2 Excel

    
    Set RngTxt = Selection.Range
    Set RngFnd = RngTxt.Duplicate
    
    Dim splChr_Devnagari, splChr_Uni, plusMinus_Devnagari, plusMinus_Uni, rKreem_Devnagari, rKreem_Uni, rKree_Devnagari, rKree_Uni, rKrim_Devnagari, rKrim_Uni, rKri_Devnagari, rKri_Uni As Variant
    Dim rKaim_Devnagari, rKaim_Uni, rKai_Devnagari, rKai_Uni, rKem_Devnagari, rKem_Uni, rKe_Devnagari, rKe_Uni As Variant
    Dim rKam_Devnagari, rKam_Uni, rKa_Devnagari, rKa_Uni, rKm_Devnagari, rKm_Uni, rK_Devnagari, rK_Uni, k_Devnagari, k_Uni As Variant
    
    
        '094D position change
    Dim buff() As String
    ReDim buff(Len(RngFnd) - 1)
    For i = 1 To Len(RngFnd)
        buff(i - 1) = Mid$(RngFnd, i, 1)
    Next
    
    '2381 velanti replace
    For i = LBound(buff) To UBound(buff)
    
    If (AscW(buff(i)) = 2367) Then
    If (i - 2 > 0) Then
        If (AscW(buff(i - 2)) = 2381) Then
        'jodakshar aahe
            If (i - 4 > 0 & AscW(buff(i - 4)) = 2381) Then
            'double jodakshar
            'akshar | 094D | akshar | 094D | akshar | velanti
            Dim zemp1 As String
            Dim zemp2 As String
            Dim zemp3 As String
            Dim zemp4 As String
            Dim zemp5 As String
            Dim zemp6 As String
            zemp6 = buff(i)
            zemp5 = buff(i - 1)
            zemp4 = buff(i - 2)
            zemp3 = buff(i - 3)
            zemp2 = buff(i - 4)
            zemp1 = buff(i - 5)
            buff(i) = zemp5
            buff(i - 1) = zemp4
            buff(i - 2) = zemp3
            buff(i - 3) = zemp2
            buff(i - 4) = zemp1
            buff(i - 5) = zemp6
            
            Else
            'single dokakshar
            'akshar | 094D | akshar | velanti
            Dim temp1 As String
            Dim temp2 As String
            Dim temp3 As String
            Dim temp4 As String
            temp4 = buff(i)
            temp3 = buff(i - 1)
            temp2 = buff(i - 2)
            temp1 = buff(i - 3)
            buff(i) = temp3
            buff(i - 1) = temp2
            buff(i - 2) = temp1
            buff(i - 3) = temp4
            End If
        Else
        'jodakshar naahi
        Dim temp5 As String
        temp5 = buff(i - 1)
        buff(i - 1) = buff(i)
        buff(i) = temp5
        End If
    Else
    Dim temp As String 'Pahilya aksharala velanti
    temp = buff(i - 1)
    buff(i - 1) = buff(i)
    buff(i) = temp
    End If
    End If
    Next
    
    RngFnd = Join(buff, "")
    
    'ü   û   f   Ÿ   ú   Äæ  ÂÂà õ   ù   ÷   ö   ¨¾à X   V   U   ¹Ü  T   S   ¹ì  ®îÈà    ®î«à    ®îªà    ®î©à    ®î§ ññ  ò   ï¼  Øàî ØZààè   ØZààç   ØZàÞ    ØZàÝ
    splChr_Devnagari = Array(ChrW(8250), ChrW(8482), ChrW(200), ChrW(201), ChrW(202), ChrW(203), ChrW(204), ChrW(205), ChrW(206), ChrW(207), ChrW(208), ChrW(209), ChrW(210), ChrW(211), ChrW(212), ChrW(213), ChrW(214), ChrW(215), ChrW(216), ChrW(217), ChrW(218), ChrW(219), ChrW(220), ChrW(221), ChrW(222), ChrW(223), ChrW(224), ChrW(225), ChrW(226), ChrW(227), ChrW(228), ChrW(229), ChrW(39), ChrW(34), ChrW(34), ChrW(39))
    splChr_Uni = Array(ChrW(2404), ChrW(2365), ChrW(2406), ChrW(2407), ChrW(2408), ChrW(2409), ChrW(2410), ChrW(2411), ChrW(2412), ChrW(2413), ChrW(2414), ChrW(2415), ChrW(48), ChrW(49), ChrW(50), ChrW(51), ChrW(52), ChrW(53), ChrW(54), ChrW(55), ChrW(56), ChrW(57), ChrW(40), ChrW(41), ChrW(42), ChrW(43), ChrW(45), ChrW(739), ChrW(8763), ChrW(47), ChrW(36), ChrW(59), ChrW(8216), ChrW(8221), ChrW(8220), ChrW(8217))
    
    For i = LBound(splChr_Uni) To UBound(splChr_Uni)
        RngFnd = Replace(RngFnd, splChr_Uni(i), splChr_Devnagari(i))
    Next
    
    '+   =   )   and numbers 1-9
    plusMinus_Devnagari = Array(ChrW(112), ChrW(48), ChrW(49), ChrW(50), ChrW(51), ChrW(52), ChrW(53), ChrW(54), ChrW(55), ChrW(56), ChrW(57), ChrW(48), ChrW(49), ChrW(50), ChrW(51), ChrW(52), ChrW(53), ChrW(54), ChrW(55), ChrW(56), ChrW(57))
    plusMinus_Uni = Array(ChrW(2365), ChrW(2406), ChrW(2407), ChrW(2408), ChrW(2409), ChrW(2410), ChrW(2411), ChrW(2412), ChrW(2413), ChrW(2414), ChrW(2415), ChrW(48), ChrW(49), ChrW(50), ChrW(51), ChrW(52), ChrW(53), ChrW(54), ChrW(55), ChrW(56), ChrW(57))
    
    For i = LBound(plusMinus_Uni) To UBound(plusMinus_Uni)
        RngFnd = Replace(RngFnd, plusMinus_Uni(i), plusMinus_Devnagari(i))
    Next
    
        '§ýK ©àK ªàK iK  ®K  °àK ²K  ³àK ´àK ¸àK ¹K  ºK  "K  ¼K  ½àK ¾àK ¿àK ÀK  ÁàK ÂàK ïÂàK    qK  ÄK  ÆàK ÇàK ÈàK ÉàK ÊK  ïÊK vK  ÍàK ÎàK ÏàK ÐàK ÑK  ÓK  ïÓK ÕàK ÖàK
    rKreem_Devnagari = Array( _
    ChrW(167) & ChrW(253) & ChrW(75), ChrW(169) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(170) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(105) & ChrW(75), ChrW(174) & ChrW(75), ChrW(176) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(178) & ChrW(75), ChrW(179) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(180) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(184) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(185) & ChrW(75), ChrW(186) & ChrW(75), ChrW(187) & ChrW(75), ChrW(188) & ChrW(75), ChrW(189) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(190) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(191) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(192) & ChrW(75), ChrW(193) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(194) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(239) & ChrW(194) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(113) & ChrW(75), ChrW(196) & ChrW(75), ChrW(198) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(199) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(200) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(201) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(202) & ChrW(75), ChrW(239) & ChrW(202) & ChrW(75), ChrW(118) & ChrW(75), ChrW(205) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(206) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(207) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), _
    ChrW(208) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(209) & ChrW(75), ChrW(211) & ChrW(75), ChrW(239) & ChrW(211) & ChrW(75), ChrW(213) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75), ChrW(214) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(75))
    
    rKreem_Uni = Array( _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2326) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2327) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2328) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2329) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2330) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2331) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2333) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2334) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2335) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2336) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2337) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2338) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2339) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2340) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2341) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2342) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2343) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2344) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2345) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2346) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2347) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2348) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2349) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2350) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2351) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2353) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2354) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2357) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2358) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2359) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2360) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2361) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2355) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2356) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(23812359) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(23812334) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306))
    
    For i = LBound(rKreem_Devnagari) To UBound(rKreem_Devnagari)
        RngFnd = Replace(RngFnd, rKreem_Uni(i), rKreem_Devnagari(i))
    Next

 
    '§G  ©àG ªàG iG  ®G  °àG ²G  ³àG ´àG ¸àG ¹G  ºG  »G  ¼G  ½àG ¾àG ¿àG ÀG  ÁàG ÂàG ïÂàG    qG  ÄG  ÆàG ÇàG ÈàG ÉàG ÊG  ïÊG vG  ÍàG ÎàG ÏàG ÐàG ÑG  ÓG  ïÓG ÕàG ÖàG
    rKem_Devnagari = Array( _
    ChrW(167) & ChrW(71), ChrW(169) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(170) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(105) & ChrW(71), ChrW(174) & ChrW(71), ChrW(176) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(178) & ChrW(71), ChrW(179) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(180) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(184) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(185) & ChrW(71), _
    ChrW(186) & ChrW(71), ChrW(187) & ChrW(71), ChrW(188) & ChrW(71), ChrW(189) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(190) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(191) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(192) & ChrW(71), ChrW(193) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(194) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(239) & ChrW(194) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), _
    ChrW(113) & ChrW(71), ChrW(196) & ChrW(71), ChrW(198) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(199) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(200) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(201) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(202) & ChrW(71), ChrW(239) & ChrW(202) & ChrW(71), ChrW(118) & ChrW(71), ChrW(205) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(206) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(207) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(208) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), _
    ChrW(209) & ChrW(71), ChrW(211) & ChrW(71), ChrW(239) & ChrW(211) & ChrW(71), ChrW(213) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71), ChrW(214) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(71))

    rKem_Uni = Array( _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2326) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2327) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2328) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2329) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2330) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2331) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2333) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2334) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2335) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2336) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2337) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2338) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2339) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2340) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2341) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2342) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2343) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2344) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2345) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2346) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2347) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2348) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2349) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2350) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2351) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2353) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2354) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2357) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2358) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2359) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2360) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2361) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2355) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2356) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2359) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2334) & ChrW(2375) & ChrW(2306))

    For i = LBound(rKem_Devnagari) To UBound(rKem_Devnagari)
        RngFnd = Replace(RngFnd, rKem_Uni(i), rKem_Devnagari(i))
    Next

    '§F  ©àF ªàF iF  ®F  °àF ²F  ³àF ´àF ¸àF ¹F  ºF  »F  ¼F  ½àF ¾àF ¿àF ÀF  ÁàF ÂàF ïÂàF    qF  ÄF  ÆàF ÇàF ÈàF ÉàF ÊF  ïÊF vF  ÍàF ÎàF ÏàF ÐàF ÑF  ÓF  ïÓF ÕàF ÖàF
    rKe_Devnagari = Array( _
    ChrW(167) & ChrW(70), ChrW(169) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(170) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(105) & ChrW(70), ChrW(174) & ChrW(70), ChrW(176) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(178) & ChrW(70), ChrW(179) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(180) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(184) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(185) & ChrW(70), ChrW(186) & ChrW(70), ChrW(187) & ChrW(70), ChrW(188) & ChrW(70), ChrW(189) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(190) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(191) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), _
    ChrW(192) & ChrW(70), ChrW(193) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(194) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(239) & ChrW(194) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(113) & ChrW(70), ChrW(196) & ChrW(70), ChrW(198) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(199) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(200) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(201) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), _
    ChrW(202) & ChrW(70), ChrW(239) & ChrW(202) & ChrW(70), ChrW(118) & ChrW(70), ChrW(205) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(206) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(207) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(208) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), _
    ChrW(209) & ChrW(70), ChrW(211) & ChrW(70), ChrW(239) & ChrW(211) & ChrW(70), ChrW(213) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70), ChrW(214) & ChrW(224) & ChrW(70))

    rKe_Uni = Array( _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2326) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2327) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2328) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2329) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2330) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2331) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(2375), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2333) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2334) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2335) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2336) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2337) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2338) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2339) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2340) & ChrW(2375), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2341) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2342) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2343) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2344) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2345) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2346) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2347) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2348) & ChrW(2375), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2349) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2350) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2351) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2353) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2354) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2357) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2358) & ChrW(2375), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2359) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2360) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2361) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2355) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2356) & ChrW(2375), ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2359) & ChrW(2375), _
    ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2334) & ChrW(2375))

    For i = LBound(rKe_Devnagari) To UBound(rKe_Devnagari)
        RngFnd = Replace(RngFnd, rKe_Uni(i), rKe_Devnagari(i))
    Next
    RngTxt.Text = RngFnd
    Selection.ClearFormatting
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Last line (in text editor no 109) of Array set to rKreem_Uni in last `ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2332) & ChrW(23812334) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306)` and second last `ChrW(2352) & ChrW(2381) & ChrW(2325) & ChrW(23812359) & ChrW(2368) & ChrW(2306)` elemenr of array the atgument passed to `ChrW()` is wrong as errpr message says (23812334 and  23812359 are not valid chars).

Comment: Unfortunally, after fixing that you get error procedure too large.  No alternatives to that code,as it is very poor programmed!

Comment: Okay. Will check here.I have created Sub procedures in my code. PFA in the question.

Comment: I have fixed the above issue. Now i am getting Run Time Error 424 at https://github.com/kaupage/UnicodeToDevnagari/blob/master/UnicodeToDevnagariInscript.bas#L422  line no 422.